# css - dropdown - z-index somehow still wrong

Tags: css

Changing templates for an Oxid eshop system, and have somehow got a z-index problem.
Theorectically everything is positioned (relative etc), and theoretically the dropdowns have a z-index, but in reality, i've still got a problem.

Problem is visible here, have made the dropdown visible

http://keith464.fahrradhamburg.de/Regale/Paletten-Regale/Einzelteile-Baukasten/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

...........................................................................

Hi now define  `z-index` property  as like this

```
.listRefine.clear.bottomRound{
position:relative;
z-index:5;
}
```

do this your result is  this

**or** ----------------------------------------------------

[image]

***or this do***   -------------------------------------------

```
.infogridView > li, .infogridView:after{
overflow:hidden; // remove this line
z-index:1; // remove this line

}

.dropDown ul{
background:#fff; // add this line

}
```

**than your result is  this**

[image]

Comment: brilliant - very helpful
added a z-index to the dropdown ul, and now seems to be working nicely

Answer (score 0):

The z-index on the .listRefine class is set to 1. Increase the z-index on the class.

> .listRefine {   z-index:5; }

I noticed that this image is failing to load aswell

> background-image: url("/bg/svg/grad_grey-light.svg");

For the dropdowns on the products you need to add a background colour, or a background image.

Comment: ok thanks, its cos i'm refractoring the css, and there are still "bits of cr*p" init :-)